# Automatically conducting t tests and chi square tests across multiple variables in a data frame in R

Tags: r, summary, chi-squared

Here is some example data:

```
set.seed(1234)    # Make the results reproducible

count <- 100
cs1 <- round(rchisq(count, 1), 2)
cs2 <- round(rchisq(count, 2), 2)
c(rep("Present", 30), rep("Absent", 30), rep("NA", 40)) -> temp
temp[temp == "NA"] <- NA
as.factor(temp) -> temp
temp1 <- round(rnorm(count, 3), 2)
temp1[7] <- NA
temp2 <- round(rnorm(count, 7), 2)
temp2[54] <- NA
c(rep("Yes", 30), rep("No", 30), rep("Maybe", 30), rep("NA", 10)) -> temp3
temp3[temp3 == "NA"] <- NA
as.factor(temp3) -> temp3
c(rep("Group A", 55), rep("Group B", 45)) -> temp4
as.factor(temp4) -> temp4
mydata <- data.frame(cs1, cs2, temp, temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4)
mydata$cs2[56:100] <- NA ; mydata
```

I know I can compute summary statistics for each variable stratified by `temp4` like so:

`by(mydata, mydata$temp4, summary)`

However, I would also like to compute either a t.test or a chisq.test for each variable stratified by `temp4`. I've tried simply modifying the above code to do that but it always gives me an error. It seems the error stems from the fact that some of the variables in the data frame are numeric (and thus, would need a t.test) while others are factors (and thus, would need a chisq.test).

Is there a simple way to tell R to check the variable to see what kind it is, and then run the appropriate test, all at once? And to still print out all of the results even if it encounters an error?

I am not worried about the appropriateness of doing this (e.g., I am aware of the risks of multiple testing, etc) but rather just need to know how to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to loop through the variables and decide inside the anonymous function which test to conduct.
When an error occurs, it's caught by `tryCatch` and instead of a test result the final list will have the error message as a member.

```
tests_list <- lapply(mydata[-ncol(mydata)], function(x){
  tryCatch({
    if(is.numeric(x)){
      if(length(levels(mydata$temp4)) == 2){
        t.test(x ~ temp4, data = mydata)
      }else{
        aov(x ~ temp4, data = mydata)
      }
    }else{
      tbl <- table(x, mydata$temp4)
      chisq.test(tbl)
    }
  }, error = function(e) e)
})

err <- sapply(tests_list, inherits, "error")

tests_list$cs1
tests_list$temp3

tests_list[[err]]
```

Comment: This worked great, but when I tried it on my real data I received a message `Error in t.test.formula(x ~ temp4, data = mydata) : grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels` - I have altered the example data above so it will now give this error when trying your code. Is there a way to avoid this? I would like it to do what you made it do, but when it runs into an error, it should just continue and still run the other analyses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can loop through designated columns, keeping `temp4` as the factor, and check class of each column (named `x` within the anonymous function). You can use `sapply` or `apply(X, MARGIN = 2, FUN ...)`. Note that I'm explicitly subsetting `mydata` because I find it more explicit and readable.

```
sapply(mydata[, c("cs1", "cs2", "temp", "temp1", "temp2", "temp3")], FUN = function(x, group) {
  if (class(x) == "numeric") {
    # perform t-test, e.g. t.test(x ~ group)
    return(result_of_t_test)
  }

  if (class(x) == "factor") {
    # perform chi-square test
    return(result_of_chisq_test)
  }
}, group = mydata$temp4)
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't able to get this code to work - all of the results it returns say `NULL`, even with the prior version of my data (which was edited, as above). Also, is there a way to write the code without putting the variable names in? My real data file has hundreds of variable names. Thanks!

Comment: @Alexander in each `if` statement, you have to return the object. If we used `if{} else {}`, this would not be necessary. As for the listing of variables, you can also exclude variables. Try using `which`, e.g. `which(!(colnames(mydata) %in% c("temp4")))`. This way you can add more variables to exclude compared to e.g. `colnames(mydata) != "temp4"`.